# migration fails as route middleware selects from non-existing table during tests

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, database-migration, laravel-5.5

I can't run tests as migration fails as a route middleware queries from a table during (or even before the start of) migration that needs to be created while migrating.

I've tried to run my test with `->withoutMiddleware()` or `->withoutMiddleware(ThatMiddleware::class)` with not much of a success.

So my current workaround is as following. In the middleware in question I do this:

```php
class ThatMiddleware extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {
        if(Schema::hasTable('table_in_question')) {
            // ... code that queries the table
        }
    }
}
```

But this seems a bit insecure especially considering the middleware is for authentication.
I'm not sure this error is a result of a poorly written middleware or test.

Is there any better way to fix this?

Comment: Are you using the `RefreshDatabase` database trait in your test?

Comment: Yes I'm using the trait.

Comment: it looks like `ThatMiddleware` is actually a service provider.

Comment: you can't query data in a service provider but you can do it in a middleware